# Why would you have multiple databindings to a WinForms control?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to learn how to use WinForms databinding, but one thing that's confusing me is why you would "Add" a databinding rather then "Set" a databinding? For example consider the following code.

`TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds,"Customers.CustomerID")`

As I understand it this line adds a databinding to `TextBox1` that binds its `Text` property to the `CustomerID` fields in the `Customers` table of the `ds` `DataSet`.

Yet to me the term "Add" implies that you can add multiple of something. Which confuses me in this example. Why would you have a textbox bound to multiple things? How could that even be possible? Can someone provide an example where multiple bindings make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also bind other fields, such as Enabled.

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", myPresentationModel, "IsTextBox1Enabled");
```

Comment: Oh man that's so obvious now thanks. So what happens if I bind twice to the same property? Like TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds,"Customers.CustomerID"); and then TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds,"Customers.CustomerName"). Does the 2nd binding to the Text property replace the first?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure it throws an exception along the lines of "duplicate binding cannot be added". (Edit: Ah, there we go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6y3aby2(v=VS.100).aspx -- "The propertyName is already data-bound.")